# How to check if a row is present in SQL Server table or not?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to check if there is a row present in a SQL Server table or not.

If the row exists (on a particular `TicketID`), it should show a messagebox that you can't continue further as there is already an entry in database. But if there isn't, it should insert some records (on that particular `TicketID`).

I tried try and catch but wasn't able to do it :

Here is the code of query: (hardcoded `ticketID` for example)

```
bool no;

try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EngineerVisited from tblTicketTechnical where TicketID=1";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        bool = rdr.GetBoolean(0);
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot continue");
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could suggest a function that will return true if row is found and return false, if it isn't.

Comment: I don't get your design. Why are you fetching EngineerVisited value from a record which shouldn't exist to begin with?

Comment: I have a TicketTechnical table in which, entries are only added if engineer has visited the site or not. If engineer has, user can close the ticket - if not, it should prompt a message that you can't close ticket as engineer has not yet visited the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `SQLDataReader`.

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the same logic in code as the logic you state in English: if there's already a ticket show a message and if not, insert some data.

```
var checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblTicketTechnical where TicketID=1";
var command = new OleDbCommand(checkQuery, con);

con.Open();
int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

if(count > 0)
{
    //Already exists, show message
}
else
{
    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblTicketTechnical(col1, col2) VALUES('val1', val2')";
    con = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, con);
    con.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Please mind that this is written out of my head and not tested. Nor have I implemented exception handling. This is just to show the logic how you can perform what you want to achieve.

Comment: EXISTS would be a better choice since there's no need to actually count all the records in the table. Otherwhise this is perfect IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

A `catch` block will only be executed if your code throws an `exception`. Here it is simply not happening.

Instead of Try/Catch use `if` statements and checks on your query results.

Answer (score 1):

Create procedure and code like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM youtable WHERE id= @id)
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Record Exists', 16, 2)
   END
ELSE
   Begin
      INSERT INTO YOURTABEL(COLUM1,COLUM2) VALUES(VALUE1, VALUE2)
   END
```

and then by try catch you can show message to user

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataTableReader.HasRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
The HasRows property returns information about the current result set
```